# Filter an SQL query SELECT statement using HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, having

I have created a select statement that brings together data from three database tables. Here's the source data from the three tables:

**Table 1:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group 1 |
| 2 | Group 2 |
| 3 | Group 3 |
| 4 | Group 4 |

**Table 2:**

| id | groupid | limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |

**Table 3:**

| id | userid | groupid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 459 | 4 |
| 2 | 521 | 4 |
| 3 | 487 | 4 |
| 4 | 121 | 3 |
| 5 | 778 | 4 |
| 6 | 123 | 4 |
| 7 | 488 | 4 |
| 8 | 74 | 4 |
| 9 | 663 | 4 |
| 10 | 741 | 4 |
| 11 | 56 | 3 |
| 12 | 222 | 3 |
| 13 | 632 | 4 |
| 14 | 115 | 4 |
| 15 | 447 | 4 |

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT name as "Group name", limit as "Membership limit", 
(SELECT count(userid) FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.groupid = Table1.id) as "Current number of members" 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.groupid = Table1.id 
ORDER BY name
```

The above query correctly brings up the data as follows:

[SQL Query Results Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thxoB.jpg)

However, I want to filter the results of this query so that the table only shows the rows where the "Current number of members" is greater than the "Membership limit". In this case, it should only show the group named 'Group 3' which has 3 current members when the membership limit is only 2.

I tried including a GROUP BY statement together with a HAVING statement, as follows:

```
SELECT name as "Group name", limit as "Membership limit", 
(SELECT count(userid) FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.groupid = Table1.id) as "Current group members"
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table2.groupid = Table1.id
GROUP BY Table1.id, Table2.limit
HAVING "Current group members" > "Membership limit"
ORDER BY name
```

This does not bring up any errors when I run the query, but it is returning no data (instead of returning the values for Group 3).

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong that will be obvious to other people and I would appreciate your expert advice!

Comment: It might be that someone here will directly have the correct idea how to fix your query, but I think it's really difficult to answer your question without seeing any input data and the expected result. Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd have expected another error...)

Comment: @JonasMetzler, thanks for your comment. I have updated my post now to include the source data. The original query is working correctly using this source data. It's just the part when I need to filter the resulting table that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @jarlh, I just tested the query out in PHPmyadmin. That's where that warning came up.

Comment: Hi again @jarlh, that warning doesn't come up now, when I use the alias "Membership limit" in the HAVING statement, so I have updated my post to simplify my question. But it is still returning no data, instead of returning the Group 3 data. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @VeronicaSwift, I've never noticed it before, but it seems like MySQL has an inconsistent meaning of double quotes. https://dbfiddle.uk/n564KGoG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your query up in a *derived table* (the subquery). Then check the number of users it returns:

```
select "Group name", "Membership limit", "Current group members"
from
(
    SELECT name as "Group name", limit as "Membership limit",
           (SELECT count(userid) FROM Table3
            WHERE Table3.groupid = Table1.id) as "Current group members"
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2
      ON Table2.groupid = Table1.id
) dt
where "Current group members" > "Membership limit"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jarlh. Unfortunately, this query is still returning no rows of data, when it should be returning:
|Group 3 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: What happens if you skip the WHERE clause for a while?

Comment: Thanks, @jarlh. When I use your derived table code and remove the final WHERE clause, it returns a table with three columns (Group name | Membership limit | Current group members).  The table has 8 rows and all 8 cells in the 'Group name' column contain the text "Group name"; all 8 cells in the 'Membership limit' column contain the text 'Membership limit'; and all 8 cells in the 'Current group members' column contain the text 'Current group members'. None of the cells contain numbers.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Double quotes are the SQL standard character to quote identifiers, but unfortunately some products use them as string delimiters.

Comment: The server runs MySQL on Linux and I’m using phpMyAdmin to do my query testing. Double quotes work fine in other queries I’ve run on this server. And shown in the image in my post above, my original code (before I tried to filter the list further) worked perfectly with the double quotes. So I don’t think the double quotes are the issue here. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: MySQL wants back-ticks instead of double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much @jarlh, that did the trick!  I'm just curious though…. the double quotes worked fine in my query above (which just presents the data in the three columns without filtering it). So why do the double quotes need to change to back-ticks when we introduce the derived table?